# Ember: create a DS.belongsTo *outside* of a Model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm wanting to ideally create a `DS.belongsTo` / `BelongsToRelationship` in my own class (which is an `Ember.Object`, but not a `DS.Model`), or alternatively recreate the functionality to let me hold a reference to a record in my own class. I don't know if it's possible to use a `DS.belongsTo` outside of a `DS.Model`, or if so, how to set it up.

#### Background:

I have an ember-cli app using ember-data + ember-fire + firebase. One of my models has an attribute which is an object holding "type specific" information for the record. I transform this object into my own class based on the *type* it describes, and some times that type will have references to other records in the database. In these cases I would like to have a `DS.belongsTo` property set up in my typeSpecific class that I could link to in the same way as linking to a relationship in a regular model.

#### Alternative:

After a lot of searching and not finding any information on how to do this I made my own class which got me most of the way there. I've just noticed that although I can change the record it references on the client side and have it update, if I change it on the server-side I don't get updates coming through, so it's back to the drawing board.

If anyone is able to tell me how to make this alternative approach work that would serve the purpose too. The idea with this class is that I pass it a model name and id, and it should create the model reference and then keep `model` and `id` in sync if either side changes, and also pass through updates if anything on the model it's connected to gets changed just like a regular relationship would.

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({

  id: null,
  table: undefined,
  model: undefined,
  store: undefined,

  init: function() {
    this._super();
    if(this.id && !this.model) {
      this.updateModel();
    }
    else if(this.model && !this.id) {
      this.updateId();
    }
  },

  updateModel: function() {
    var self = this;
    if( this.get('id') ) {
      this.store.find(this.get('table'), this.get('id')).then( function(model) {
         self.set('model', model);
      });
    }
    else {
      self.set('model', undefined);
    }
  }.observes('id','table'),

  updateId: function() {
    if(this.get('model')) {
      this.set('id', this.get('model.id'));
    }
    else {
      this.set('id', null);
    }
  }.observes('model'),
});
```

Edit: code to manipulate the object above:

```
//Creating a reference:
this.set('target', ModelPointer.create({store:this.get('store'), table:this.get('targetTable'), id:targetId}));

//or:
this.set('target', ModelPointer.create({store:store, table:'myTable'}));
...
this.set('target.id', '42');
```

I believe that at the moment if I change either the `id` or `model` on the client the other will update automatically, eg:

```
//either:
this.set('target.id', '43');
//or:
this.store.find('myTable','43').then( function(newModel) {
  self.set('target.model', newModel);
});
```

The problem is that if I log into Firebase and change `myTable['42'].name='Fred'` then the value showing on my web page which is linked to `target.model.name` doesn't update to 'Fred'. I suspect that if I set `target.model.name` to 'Fred' on the client side and save it wouldn't update the value on the server either(?)

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to manipulate the reference on the client and on the server?

Comment: @Oren - thanks for your interest; please see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest solution I've come up is to not store the `id` separately (left to the model itself). I've verified that changes I make in Firebase propagate to the displayed entry just fine.

With this solution setting the referenced model can be done with either its `id` or simply the model instance itself. See the controller code for examples.

Firstly, for reference, some test data for Firebase:

```js
{
  "testModels": {
    "1": {
      "name": "Model one"
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "The second model"
    },
    "3": {
      "name": "Third is the charm"
    }
  }
}
```

Thus its model `app/models/test-model.js` just needs the name in there.

Here is my `belongsTo`-like proxy class, I put mine under `app/utils/proxy-class.js` but it should probably be a Mixin:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
  remote: null, // reference to the remote DS.Model

  store: null, // reference to the actual store
  storeModel: null, // name of the model in the store

  _watchRemote: function() {
    var self = this;
    if ( typeof self.get('remote') === 'object' ) {
      // do nothing, already an object
      if ( ! Ember.isPresent( self.get('store') ) ) {
        // but set the store from the model
        self.set( 'store', self.get('remote.store') );
      }
    } else if ( typeof self.get('remote') === 'string' ||
                typeof self.get('remote') === 'number' ) {
      // it's an id, so fetch the model
      self._fetchModel( self.get('remote') );
    }
  }.observes('remote').on('init'), // on change, and during object init

  _fetchModel: function( id ) {
    var self = this;
    self.store.find( self.get('storeModel'), id ).then(
      function( model ) {
        self.set( 'remote', model );
      }, function ( err ) {
        console.error( "couldn't read from the store:", err );
      });
  },
});
```

I created this controller, and used the browser console to change the model on the fly to test that model changes are picked up:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';
import proxyClass from '../utils/proxy-class';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  model: {
    remoteFromId: null,
    remoteFromModel: null,
  },

  init: function() {
    var self = this;

    self.set( 'model.remoteFromId',
      proxyClass.create({
        remote: 1,
        store: self.get('store'),
        storeModel: 'test-model',
      })
    );

    self.get('store').find( 'test-model', 2 )
      .then( function( model ) {
        self.set( 'model.remoteFromModel',
          proxyClass.create({
            remote: model,
            storeModel: 'test-model',
            // no store provided here: set from the model
          })
        );
      });

  }
});
```

And the template for the controller:

```html
<p>remoteFromId: {{model.remoteFromId.remote.id}}
  {{model.remoteFromId.remote.name}}</p>
<p>remoteFromModel: {{model.remoteFromModel.remote.id}}
  {{model.remoteFromModel.remote.name}}</p>
```

Comment: thanks for the really thorough answer! What I'm still seeing with this solution is that updating things on the client side propagates the changes around fine, but making a change in Firebase doesn't propagate the updates to the client side. Any thoughts?

Comment: That works fine for me, no problems getting the update through to my template. Are you using `.get()` and friends, or bound properties in the templates to read them? Without observers you wouldn't notice the changes.

Comment: Ah, my problem was with a computed property watching `proxy.remote` when it should have been watching `proxy.remote.name`, (and an issue with my data meaning that when I fixed the first problem the results stayed the same). This solution appears to work perfectly!